# leaflet Layer type casting

Tags: typescript, leaflet

This piece of code works fine but Typescript compiler show errors and I can't figure out how to do the right casting or generic method calls. Any hints?

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
const importGeoJSON = (featureCollection: GeoJSON.FeatureCollection) => {
    let geoLayer = L.geoJSON(featureCollection)

    geoLayer.getLayers().forEach((layer ) => {
        if (layer._latlng) {
            var latlng = layer.getLatLng();
        } else {
            var latlng = layer.getLatLngs();
        }
        switch (layer.feature!.properties.type) {
            case "rectangle":
                new L.Rectangle(latlng, layer.options).addTo(map);
                break;
            case "polygon":
                new L.Polygon(latlng, layer.options).addTo(map);
                break;
            default:
                new L.Polygon(latlng, layer.options).addTo(map);
                break;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: For starters, what *are* the errors? I'm not a TypeScript compiler and jcalz isn't a TypeScript compiler either (although sometimes it appears to be the case). Even if I paste your code into a playground, I [get these errors](https://tsplay.dev/WGApJN). Are these the errors you are referring to?

Comment: I'm indeed referring to these errors. Sorry for not mentioning them.

Comment: maybe you're using non-public / unsupported APIs? looking at what folks have committed to the [definitely typed repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/92e7d4c5bcfb459df1a58b41ebf3b8f2b78f9c7d/types/leaflet/index.d.ts#L1191-L1229), `_latlng`, `getLatLng`, `getLatLngs` and `options` aren't part of Layer's public API. not even if you go looking through its inheritance tree. it matches [Leaflet's docs too](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer).

Comment: honestly you might want to rethink your approach here. you _can_ coerce [a pretty funky type cast](https://tsplay.dev/WzPM3N) if you really want to. but then that only uncovers the issue where L.Rectangle and L.Polygon don't actually share the same parameters.

Comment: Thanks @worc for your input. As you guessed I'm more looking fora "standard" approach  with this API. `_latlng` is not in the public API since it is a pseudo private property that I propably should not use. However `getLatLngs` and `feature` are well defined in `Polyline` class (extended by `Polygon` and then by `Rectangle`).

Comment: I ended up simplifying the expression and casting `layer` to `L.Polygon`.  [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZXzEw). I don't understand why I cannot type `layer` at its instanciation though.